# What Mikuni carb model do I have?

Tags: carburetor, yamaha

I have a Yamaha XS750 1979 rebuilt as a cafe racer (not by me). I need to buy some parts for the carb, but cant seem to find out what carb I have - no ID number
anywhere. I think the original is called BS34 but not sure.

Can anyone help me please ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the model number, but the parts diagram for the original looks like what your photos show.

[image]

http://www.partzilla.com/parts/search/Yamaha/Motorcycle/1979/XS750F/CARBURETOR/parts.html

Comment: thanks a lot - so I´ll go with the BS34 original and will try to find the parts I need.

Comment: @bongobrown - It should be noted each carb (left, right, center) has is a different carburetor (each has it's own part number and description).

Answer (score 2):

I believe they are a BS38 Constant Velocity (CV) Mikuni Carb. Look at the center pair of images, which are a dual setup, but appears to be the same. According to this they were used from 1976-1979, which fits your description.

[image]