# Mikuni 1GF3 Pilot Screw

Tags: carburetor, suzuki

I have a Mikuni !GF3 carb off of a 199 Suzuki Gz250 that was brought to me partially disassembled and I cannot find the specs for the amount of turns for the pilot screw. All I can find is "preset". Does anyone have any information on this?

Answer (score 1):

That's an old bike then "199 Suzuki Gz250",

However the document shown as an answer to this question below mentions 1.5 turns out from bottom, but then mentions 2.5 to 3 to improve idle...

[What Mikuni carb model do I have?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/42790/what-mikuni-carb-model-do-i-have?rq=1)